# How to pattern match wrapped variables in PROLOG without the cut?

Tags: design-patterns, prolog, pattern-matching, wrapper, prolog-cut

I have a very simple question for Prolog programmers. This should be very easy, but I don't have any experience with that language so please help.
I am trying to interpret some simple programming language in Prolog. In this language i can have two types of variables - simple variables and array variables. I have a function that calculates the value of given variable:

```
%calc(+var, +state, -result)
```

Variable can be either a simple variable like `x` or array variable like `array(ident, index)`. I don't know how I should write that function in Prolog, so it does different things for regular and array variables. I've come up with something like this:

```
calc(array(Ident,I), S, R) :- calculating R for array var, !.
calc(Ident, S, R) :- calculating R for regular var.
```

This works, but there must be some better way.

Comment: There isn't really much detail here to say whether there's a much better way, but what you have there looks reasonable. If you want to avoid the cut, you could do `calc(Ident, S, R) :- ( Ident = array(Id, I) -> calc_array(Id, I, S, R) ; calc_var(Ident, S, R)` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, i was trying to avoid the cut and this looks like a good way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a clean way to do it: Use a dedicated wrapper for variables, so you can identify them via pattern matching. For example:

```
calc(array(Ident,I), S, R)  :- calculating R for array var.
calc(variable(Ident), S, R) :- calculating R for regular var.
```

I used the functor `variable/1` to identify variables.

No `!/0` is needed to handle this representation, and you can use your predicates as true relations, i.e. in all directions.

You may need a preprocessing step that wraps variables with a dedicated functor during or after parsing a given program. After that, you have this clean representation and can use pattern matching throughout the remainder of your program.